# How to handle the dict of parms in tornado?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tornado

I am new to tornado framework.When I open the url http://www.sample.com/index.html?roomid=1&presenterid=2 the tornado.web.RequestHandler need to handle the dict of parms. Please see the below code,

```
class MainHandler(tornado.web.RequestHandler):
    def get(self, **kwrgs):
        self.write('I got the output ya')

application = tornado.web.Application([
    (r"/index.html?roomid=([0-9])&presenterid=([0-9])", MainHandler),
])
```

My question is how to write the regular expression url ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Query string parameters are not passed as keyword arguments. Use [`getargument`](http://www.tornadoweb.org/en/stable/web.html#tornado.web.RequestHandler.get_argument):

```
class MainHandler(tornado.web.RequestHandler):
    def get(self):
        roomid = self.get_argument('roomid', None)
        presenterid = self.get_argument('presenterid', None)
        if roomid is None or presenterid is None:
            self.redirect('/') # root url
            return
        self.write('I got the output ya {} {}'.format(roomid, presenterid))

application = tornado.web.Application([
    (r"/index\.html", MainHandler),
])
```

Comment: Excellent working great. But roomid and presenterid must be integers. How can I handle this.

Comment: @dhana, What do you want to be occurred when non-integer value is passed?

Comment: I need to redirect them to root url and display a flash notice that room id/presenter-id doesnot exist

Comment: @dhana, I updated the code to redirect to root url if room-id/presenter-id is not passed.