# Python Tornado get URL arguments

Tags: python, tornado

I'm trying to inspect a request's argument before the `get()` is invoked. I have a route which is described as so:

```
user_route = r"/users/key=(?P<key>\w+)"
app = web.Application([
        web.URLSpec(user_route, user_manager.UserHandler), ..])
```

Next, (in the handler) `prepare()` is used to inspect the request before `get()`.

```
def prepare(self):
    # inspect request arguments
    print(self.request.arguments) # prints "{}"
```

The problem I'm having is that I cannot access the arguments from `prepare()`. The last statement prints an empty dict. My `get()` successfully uses the arguments as they are passed in the function like this:

```
def get(self, key):
      print(key) #works
```

How do I access arguments in `prepare()`? I have also tried `self.argument('key')` which gives an error "400 GET .... Missing argument key", but requested URL does have a key argument in it.

Comment: Similar: [How to handle the dict of parms in tornado?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18458392/55075)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In your code `key` is not a GET-argument, it's a part of a `path`. [tornado.we.URLSpec](http://www.tornadoweb.org/en/stable/web.html?#tornado.web.URLSpec) passes any capturing groups in the regex into the handler’s `get/post/etc` methods as arguments.

`tornado.web.RequestHandler` has [RequestHandler.path_args](http://www.tornadoweb.org/en/stable/web.html?#tornado.web.RequestHandler.path_args) and [RequestHandler.path_kwargs](http://www.tornadoweb.org/en/stable/web.html?#tornado.web.RequestHandler.path_kwargs) which contain the positional and keyword arguments from `URLSpec`. Those are available in `prepare` method:

```
def prepare(self):
    # inspect request arguments
    print(self.path_kwargs) # prints {"key": "something"}
```

Answer (score 5):

As Gennady Kandaurov mentioned, you passed the `key` as a part of the we.URLSpec path and you can access it using Tornado's `self.path_kwargs`. If you wanted to pass it as an argument you could used [RequestHandler.get_argument](http://www.tornadoweb.org/en/stable/_modules/tornado/web.html#RequestHandler.get_argument) to get the argument on your `get` method and use `self.request.arguments` on your `prepare` method to access it as your initial intention.

Your code could be as follow:

```
class Application(tornado.web.Application):
    def __init__(self):
        user_route = r"/users"
        app = tornado.web.Application([
            tornado.web.url(user_route, user_manager.UserHandler), ..])

class UserHandler(tornado.web.RequestHandler):
    def get(self):
        key = self.get_argument('key')
        print(key)

    def prepare(self):
        # inspect request arguments
        print(self.request.arguments)
```

Please let me know if you have any further question.

Comment: The above solution seems more appropriate for me, but thanks for correct response too.

Answer (score 2):

It's generally bad to use a character like `=` in a URL *path fragment*, since they are generally used for query arguments. Either don't use it:

```
`r"/users/(?P<key>\w+)"`
```

or turn it into a proper query argument

```
`r"/users/\?key=(?P<key>\w+)"`
```

Otherwise it's confusing for a maintainer to try to figure out which scheme you intended to use (did you really want to route a path fragment called `/key%3D\w+`? Or did you really mean you wanted a query arg and forgot the `?`?)

In any case, for URL path fragment matching ("slug-matching"), using argument unpacking can let you access them in the handler too, without having to invoke `path_kwargs`:

```
# `r"/users/(?P<key>\w+)"`
class Handler(RequestHandler):
    def get(self, **kwargs):
        key = kwargs.get('key')
        # I prefer dict.get() here, since if you change the `+` to a `*`,
        # it's possible that no key was supplied, and kwargs['key']
        # will throw a KeyError exception
```

If you intended to use a query argument for `key`, then @afxentios's answer is appropriate. (You can also use `self.get_query_argument('key')` which will explicitly only look for query arguments in the URL (whereas `get_argument` also checks in the request BODY for a www-url-encoded argument (such as if you `POST`)).